# Is endorsement object accessible in platform licence or in development org?

Tags: soql

I want to get endorsement data in soql, not able to see endorsement object in my development org. Any help ?

Comment: What do you mean by endorsement data in SOQL?

Comment: In Chatter, One can endorse someone on Particular Topic under Knowledgeable People Section  on Topic details page. Chatter rest API returns list of Endorsee + Endorser pair. Its too much data if 500 people have been endorsed on same topic in an organization. If I can get this info through object, group by can be used in soql to get only Endorsee + Count of Endorsers.